# Should the definite article be included on this sign ("common area" or "the common area")?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Someone (guess it was the administrator) put a sign on a wall in my building saying "no smoking in common area", now I wonder if that is correct, shouldn't it be "no smoking in THE common area" or "no smoking in the building / no smoking in common area of the building"? I'm always struggling with articles.

Comment: Signs often use terse language like this. Articles are usually omitted.

Comment: Further to Barmar's Comment, is the more simple and more common wording, 'No smoking' a complete expression, or a useful abbreviation? Further still, why would you suggest 'no smoking in common area of the building' rather than '… in the common area…' or '… in common areas…'?

Struggling with articles is a recognised characteristic of Central/Eastern European learners of English, perhaps among others… which reinforces my view that this Question belongs to English Language Learners, not here in ELU…

Comment: By all means write an open letter questioning the educational values of the author and post it right next to the offending sign.

Comment: Why would you put "no smoking in common area of the building"? I can't recall ever seeing a no smoking sign telling people to not smoke in a different building.

Answer (score 0):

Signs are often written in a version of "headlinese" that omits words like articles. So signs say "beware of dog" instead of "beware of *the* dog," "keep off grass" instead of "keep off *the* grass," "use other door" instead of "use *the* other door," *et cetera.*